# Update Feature records in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I have to update multiple feature records in ArcGIS through ArcObjects. 
Below is my code.

It's running fine for first time but it's giving me error while it's going to run the queryfilter for nexttime it's giving me error "**Insufficient permissions**".

```c#
foreach (test toProcess in forProcess)

{
                    int OID = toProcess.R1;
                    int GISID = toProcess.R2;
                    double sLength = toProcess.R3;

                    string wherec = "OBJECTID = '" + OID + "' AND GISID = '" + GISID + "'";


                //initialize queryfilter
                queryFilter.SubFields = "*";
                queryFilter.WhereClause = wherec;

                //search through queryfilter
                IFeatureCursor featureCursor2 = featureClass.Search(queryFilter, false);
                //Get the output features 
                IFeature featurenew = featureCursor2.NextFeature();

                //while (featurenew != null) (not using as at a time only 1 feature)
                //{
                    IObject pObject = featurenew;
                    int iNewTag = GISAUConstants.kiNoSequenceValue;

                    // Get a new tag value from tag sequence within workspace.
                    iNewTag = CommonFunct.GetSequenceValue(GISAUConstants.ksGISIDSequenceName, workspace);

                    if (iNewTag <= GISAUConstants.kiNoSequenceValue)
                        throw new Exception("Invalid tag value: " + iNewTag);

                    // Get the field index, by model name.
                    int fieldIndex = CommonFunct.GetFirstFieldIndexByModelName(pObject, GISAUConstants.ksMNFieldGISID);

                    // Did we get a valid field index?
                    if (fieldIndex == GISAUConstants.kiNoField)
                        throw new Exception(" does not have field with model name: " + GISAUConstants.ksMNFieldGISID);

                    // All is well... write tag value to the field.
                    featurenew.set_Value(fieldIndex, iNewTag);
                    featurenew.Store();
                    //featureselection.Clear();

                    logger.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Object ID : " + OID + " Previous GISID : " + OID + " >> New GISID : " + iNewTag);

                    //featurenew = featureCursor.NextFeature(); (as I have only single feature)
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must release the cursor after each usage. Just add these lines at the end of your codes:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(featureCursor2);
featureCursor2 = null;
```

And add a reference to ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Local assembly.